# Ensuring `random` 3 digit number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create the `3` digit random number using the following function:

```
gridView.generateData = function( size ) {

        var newData = [];

        var size = size || 100;
        var baseSize = 0;

        while( baseSize < size ) {
            baseSize++;
            newData.push( {
                "mk" : Math.floor( Math.random()*999 ) + 100 //3 digit
            } );
        }       
        return $q.all( newData );
    }
```

But in the out put `object` i see there is number of instance having `4` digit numbers to. how to insure only `3` digit using the above function?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You are generating a random number between 0-999 then adding 100 to it.....

Comment: remove +100 from calculation

Comment: simple 1 digit (first one) from 1 to 9  : `Math.ceil(Math.random()*9)`
simple 1 digit (others) from 0 to 9 : `Math.floor(Math.random()*10)`
and you can do a concatenation

Comment: if you want to get random numbers between 100 to 999 .you can use this code Math.floor(Math.random()*(999-100+1)+100)

Comment: @subbu1191 - can you update your suggestion as answer? it works fine.

Comment: @user2024080 updated as a answer..:)

Comment: @user2024080 Did you resolve the problem yet? :) I'm curious for your answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

if you want to generate 3 digit random numbers between 100 - 999 then you can try the below solution

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*(999-100+1)+100);
```

Comment: would be nice to mention that `~~` does the same as `Math.floor` ;) +1

Comment: Why have you kept `999-100+1` as an equation, why not just change it to `900`?

Comment: Math.floor(Math.random()*(end Number - start Number +1) + start Number) -  generic formula  to  generate a random number with in range.

(end Number - start Number + 1 ) =  the number of possible results
Math.random() = 0 to 1 .
since we need numbers between 100 and 999 in this case we want to add the start number

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your code is that you are using `+100` in your number, it will give 4-digits numbers for all generated numbers that are greater than `900`: `900+100=1000`.

**Solution:**

If you want to ensure that your `number` is always a 3-digits number(`>=100`), you can do it like this:

```
var number;
do {
  number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999);
} while (number < 100);
```

You should just test upon this `number` until it's `>=100`, instead of adding `100` to it because it can give you numbers with `4` digits.

**Demo:**

Here's a live Demo which allows only numbers between `100` and `999`:

```js
var number;
do {
  number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999);
} while (number < 100);
console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variable for the digits. Then build the 10 potency otu of the digits and use this number as factor and as value to add for getting the digits with slice from the right side.

Later, you could return an obejct with a numerical value or some other formatting of the result.

```js
function generateData(size) {
    var digits = 3;
    return Array.apply(null, { length: size || 100 }).map(function () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, digits) + Math.pow(10, digits)).toString().slice(-digits);
    });
}

console.log(generateData());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is the only one that HASNT generated 4 and 2 digit numbers so far.

This should be the accepted answer :P. Have an upvote miss.

Answer (score 1):

I had to face myself almost the same problem (generating "something" in the range from "000" to "999") and decided to use:

```js
var round = 10;
while( round > 0 ) {
    round--;
    console.log( Math.random().toString().concat("0".repeat(3)).substr(2,3) );
}
```

Should remember that Math.random() returns a random number between 0 (inclusive), and 1 (exclusive). You may get "0.001" or even "0.0001" (that is lot of leading zeros on the decimal part), so multiply by 1000 or 999 would not lead to the result I desired.

Comment: but "014", "088" - is invalid

Comment: @user2024080, not in my case, since I needed to generate "something" in the range from "000" to "999". Taht is, 0 is always a valid digit. Do you need to suppress leading zeros?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add 100. Otherwise you will overflow.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16093885)

Comment: @DanielA.White Firstly this does not work for the OP and secondly, its too short for an answer, no explanation therefore marked as low quality post. 
You with 128K+ reputation should know that. :)

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal theres nothing as too short of an answer.

Comment: @DanielA.White I do not wish to disagree with you. but then why was your answer marked as a low quality post and what does **length** stand for in _This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content._

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right path, but that `+100` was not necessary, as shown below:

```
gridView.generateData = function( size ) {
    var newData = [];

    var size = size || 100;
    var baseSize = 0;
    var digit = ~~( Math.random()*999 );

    while(digit < 100) {
        digit = ~~( Math.random()*999 );
    }

    if(digit >= 100) {
        while( baseSize < size ) {
            baseSize++;
            newData.push( {
                "mk" : digit //3 digits
            });
        }

        return $q.all( newData );
    }
}
```

As `Math.random()` returns a `float` between `0` and `1`, so just multiply it by `999` without the `+100`.

Comment: Your suggestion give even single and double digits too.. https://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/mvuLvbn2/

Comment: @user2024080 that's a separate issue theres patterns on how to pad leading 0's if thats waht you want.

Comment: @user2024080 so you only want it to be above the 100? then you need to put the variable outside of the send and just put in an `if` statement to check if its above the 100

Comment: Why "multiply it by 999"? Math.random() returns a random number between 0 (inclusive),  and 1 (exclusive).

Answer (score 0):

**Your code problem**

if you add `+100`.its append `4` digit number .If you remove the `100`. its append below `3` digit number

***So better*** use like this, `parseInt(Math.floor(math.random()*100000).toString().substring(0,3))` .Generate random num with above 4 digit, then cut the string with `3`digit. And finally convert into integer .In this method they prevent the below  and above`3` digit value.

```js
var newData = [];

        var size =100;
        var baseSize = 0;

        while( baseSize < size ) {
            baseSize++;
            newData.push( {
                "mk" : parseInt(Math.floor( Math.random()*100000).toString().substring(0,3))
            } );
        }       
      console.log( newData );
```

Comment: Does not work when Math.random() returns 0.0001 or less.

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = 0;
var digits = '';

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    digits = digits + number.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't allow for a three digit number below 100 (ie. `001`).

This oneliner will return from `000` to `999`.

```
var rand='',d=0; while(d<3){rand+=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);d++}
```